# importing mysql data with pyspark: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am new with `pyspark` and want to work with `SQL` data. Here is what I done so far.

- I can import `JSON, TXT, CSV` file formats into spark with no problem.
- I cannot for some reason connect to mysql (hosted locally : `127.0.0.1`)

I used following connection:

```
from os.path import expanduser, join, abspath
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row,DataFrameReader, SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
sparkClassPath = os.getenv('SPARK_CLASSPATH', './mysql-connector-java-8.0.11/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar')
sqlContext = SQLContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/",driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                                       dbtable = "product",user="root",password='').load()
```

It generates following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-bfc4c079a8b3> in <module>()
      3 from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
      4 sparkClassPath = os.getenv('SPARK_CLASSPATH', './mysql-connector-java-8.0.11/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar')
----> 5 sqlContext = SQLContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
      6 sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/",driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
      7                                        dbtable = "product",user="root",password='').load()

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    332         with SparkContext._lock:
    333             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 334                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    335             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    336 

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 118                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    119         except:
    120             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    178 
    179         # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 180         self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    181         # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    182         self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py in _initialize_context(self, jconf)
    271         Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    272         """
--> 273         return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
    274 
    275     @classmethod

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1399         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1400         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1401             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1402 
   1403         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:501)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1218)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:481)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:210)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please note mysql is up and running. Screenshot below

[image]

And so is pyspark

[image]

Comment: Description of the problem doesn't reflect the traceback. Your code fails on `SQLContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())` (due to problems with address binding) and doesn't reach JDBC reader part.

Comment: thanks  user9613318. Do you have a recommendation on how to make that work?

Comment: Hard to say. Permission / firewall issue? Incorrect configuration? Why did you tag it with [databricks]?

Comment: Ok. Now if I replace line you have pointed with sqlContext = SQLContext, it generates "AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: And I am admin in this machine.

Comment: The problem is not the line as such (the code is fine). Spark just cannot bind to the desired address.

Comment: I actually checked here /etc/hosts/ and replaced /added 127.0.0.1 (just in case), Restarted spark. Does not seem to work. Its driving me crazy :)